# Does homosexuality in males steeply decline with age?

Tags: sexuality

The 2013 book *[My Genes Made Me Do It! Homosexuality and the Scientific Evidence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0473174863)* ([text](http://www.mygenes.co.nz/mgmmdi_pdfs/2018FullBook.pdf)) argues that homosexuality is, at most, only weakly and indirectly genetically based, and that [conversion therapies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_therapy) are effective.

As part of this argument, it claims that homosexuality decreases in men as they age, using old Kinsey data to support it: (from page 49-50)

> Although the Kinsey surveys of 1948 and 1953 greatly exaggerated homosexual and bisexual numbers, they showed one interesting
>   trend, also borne out by subsequent studies—**a steady decline in
>   homosexual fantasy and activity with increasing age** compared with
>   heterosexuals

[image]

Is there good evidence that, as men get older, there is a decline in their homosexuality (both fantasy and activity) at a faster rate than their heterosexuality.

---

[Related question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/do-50-of-self-reported-homosexual-teens-no-longer-self-report-as-homosexual-by) which did not receive a useful answer; the only answer explained how survey answers were of limited reliability.

Comment: I made a major edit to remove the speculation and focus on the claim.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87873/discussion-on-question-by-user134593-does-homosexuality-in-males-steeply-decline).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Properly conducted [longitudinal studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3215279/) have found that, if anything, the trend is in the opposite direction.

> Only two longitudinal and prospective studies have examined changes in sexual identity over time, both of which were conducted among young women (Diamond, 2000; 2003; Sophie, 1986). Although no comparable studies exist on the sexual identity development of males, three longitudinal studies of young men have examined changes in sexual attractions (Dickson, Paul, & Herbison, 2003; Stokes, Damon, & McKirnan, 1997; Stokes, McKirnan, & Burzette, 1993). Taken together, the studies have found considerable consistency, as well as change, in sexual self-identification and attractions over time. For example, among 80 female youths (65% college students, and over sampled for youths who did not self-identify as lesbian, bisexual, or straight), Diamond (2000; 2003) found that 70% were consistent in their self-identification as lesbian, bisexual or unlabeled after two years and 50% were consistent after five years. An additional 15% transited to a lesbian or bisexual identity after two years, as did 14% after five years. Few youths transited from a lesbian, bisexual, or unlabeled identity to a straight identity. Among 216 behaviorally bisexual men (ages 18 – 30 years), Stokes and colleagues (1997) found that over the course of one year, 49% reported no changes in sexual orientation, 34% became more homosexually oriented, and 17% more heterosexually oriented. Clearly, the consistency and change documented by these various research studies must now be understood.

Regarding the quoted graph, Kinsey's report was based on self-selected interviewees and no attempt was made to obtain a representative sample. At the time this was ground-breaking research because merely talking about the subject was considered taboo, but you cannot trust any statistics derived from these interviews because of the number of potential confounding factors.

In particular, the graph shows a huge hump in category #6 at ages 13-15 and the smaller one for category #3, but nothing at that age in categories #4 and #5. This lack of correlation between the different categories strongly suggests some kind of sampling artefact.

Two possible explanations that occur to me are:

- This data may have come from Kinsey's [interviews with paedophiles](https://web.archive.org/web/20130123084849/http://www.kinseyinstitute.org/about/controversy%202.htm), who cannot be considered to have valid opinions on their victim's sexuality.
- At the time there was widespread ignorance about all aspects of sex, and sex education beyond a "birds and bees" talk from a parent was very rare. Some of Kinsey's interview subjects may have had homosexual attraction or experiences during adolescence and only later found out that what they were doing was considered taboo. They would then repress any homosexual tendency and report that they had since become straight.

I can't prove either of these theories, but they explain the graph shown at least as well as the theory that homosexuals turn straight as they get older.

Lastly, even if sexual orientation does tend to turn straight with age, this is not evidence against a genetic component because ageing in general [has a genetic component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetics_of_aging).

Comment: The Kinsey survey has an eve more glaring flaw. Because he didn't do a longitudinal study following specific people over time, the data is strongly confounded by the environment that existed when the surveyed people were young. Eg 50 year olds were young at a time when attitudes to homosexuality were (possibly) far more intolerant. So the sample might be strongly influenced by historic changes in tolerance not individual changes in inherent preferences.

Comment: @matt_black Yes I thought about that, but AIUI attitudes throughout the early 20th century were uniformly negative, so it seemed less likely. Of course we could carry on spinning just-so stories forever. I just wanted to show that there are alternative explanations.

Comment: The quote claims a decline in homosexual *activity and fantasys*, not a decline in number that identify themselves as homosexual.  Since sexual activity in general likely decreases in upper age it is possible that the number identifying as homosexual (as they become confident of their attraction) can go up even as homosexual activity goes down due to lack general lowered sexual activity as one ages.

Comment: @dsollen The Kinsey scale is about the relative frequency of homosexual and heterosexual activity and desire, not the absolute amount.

Comment: The study you cite by Rosario et al seems to have involved youths ages 14-21 who were tracked for 12 months.  The claim in question seems to be about much longer time frames and older age, and it's not clear that it's safe to extrapolate.  The other studies cited in the Rosario paper also seem to have involved relatively young participants and time frames of five years or less.

Comment: @NateEldredge True. But it's the only data that seems to be available, so I cited it.

Comment: The study from Stokes looks pretty flawed.  In particular, they recruited study-participants from newspaper-ads looking for gay/bisexual men, then asked them about their history.  So, the fact that they found fewer men who came to identify as straight isn't surprising, as they didn't invite such men to participate in the study.

Answer (score 0):

That book is pretty much garbage. There’s an interesting RationalWiki article about [My Genes Made Me Do It](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/My_Genes_Made_Me_Do_It), however it’s rather incomplete. Regardless, I believe the author used Laumanns 1994 self reporting survey of Americans, and simply because less old people reported a gay orientation he used it to infer that people’s homosexuality declines with age. Obviously the more sensible conclusion to draw is the fact that many older people grew up in a very socially conservative period and were married to women, thus identified as heterosexual. Keep in mind they had to do face to face and phone interviews, so admitting you were gay would be a bit hard if you had a wife. Identity is very different from your actual attractions. That’s why so much social science is flawed, because ideally we need a mind reader to determine people’s true sexual orientation.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) This answer seems largely based on your speculation and opinion of an entire field of science. We expect claims to be referenced. You provide a reference, but it isn't clear that it supports your views.